# How can I tint a UIImage with gradient?

Tags: iphone, uiimage, core-graphics, drawrect, tint

I searched everywhere but didn't find the solution. I have image 1. How can I programatically tint them with gradient to get images 2 and 3? Here are those images:

[image: images 1, 2, 3]

Tints that I applied to them via Photoshop are simple 2-color linear gradients.

And my question is: how can I achieve this effect programatically?

---

**Solution:** jrtc27 gave me *almost* working example. I fixed it (for ARC) and made it reusable (using UIImage's category). Here is it:

```
- (UIImage *)tintedWithLinearGradientColors:(NSArray *)colorsArr {
    CGFloat scale = self.scale;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(self.size.width * scale, self.size.height * scale));
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, self.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeNormal);
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width * scale, self.size.height * scale);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, self.CGImage);

    // Create gradient

    UIColor *colorOne = [colorsArr objectAtIndex:1]; // top color
    UIColor *colorTwo = [colorsArr objectAtIndex:0]; // bottom color


    NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)colorOne.CGColor, (id)colorTwo.CGColor, nil];
    CGColorSpaceRef space = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(space, (__bridge CFArrayRef)colors, NULL);

    // Apply gradient

    CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, self.CGImage);
    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, CGPointMake(0,0), CGPointMake(0,self.size.height * scale), 0);
    UIImage *gradientImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return gradientImage;
}
```

Comment: Kevin O'Neill has a tint category on UIImage in his Useful Bits library, it takes a single UIColor as a parameter to use for the tinting, but you may be able to adapt it to put a gradient background in the drawing context instead of a solid color: https://github.com/kevinoneill/Useful-Bits

Comment: Yeah, but I don't know how to make a gradient with CG...

Comment: CGGradient: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGradient/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004880

Comment: I found a small bug in the code above.  I think that CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, self.size.height); should be CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, self.size.height*scale);

Comment: @RossKimes Yes, I also found this bug. Without this scale factor. The image will be cut off.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

EDIT: Here is a version which supports non-retina and retina displays

The method can be used as a category for `UIImage`

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithGradient:(UIImage *)img startColor:(UIColor *)color1 endColor:(UIColor *)color2 {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(img.size, NO, img.scale);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, img.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeNormal);
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, img.size.width, img.size.height);
    //CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, img.CGImage);

    // Create gradient
    NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)color2.CGColor, (id)color1.CGColor, nil];
    CGColorSpaceRef space = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(space, (__bridge CFArrayRef)colors, NULL);

    // Apply gradient
    CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, img.CGImage);
    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, CGPointMake(0,0), CGPointMake(0, img.size.height), 0);
    UIImage *gradientImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    CGGradientRelease(gradient);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(space);

    return gradientImage;
}
```

Edit: added change by sobri

Comment: +1 for fixing the scaling issue with retina images.  It looks like your `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions()` line fixed my issues.

Comment: I found that removing the `CGContextDrawImage`call improved the resulting images. With it included, the images have rough edges (because the original image is drawn beneath the gradient).

Comment: @sobri good catch, I changed the answer. It was not noticeable in my case where the image and the background had the same color, but with different colors this is a big improvement

Comment: @remy I found one case where you need to keep the underlying image: If you want to apply a tint (ie a gradient with alpha) instead of an opaque gradient, then you still need to draw in the original image. But otherwise, the results are better without :)

Comment: @remy all these code has to be called from the `drawRect()` method right?

Comment: @remy how would the start and end points be for a diagonal (0,0) to (1,1) gradient?

Answer (score 23):

Swift 4 version.

```
import UIKit

extension UIImage {

func tintedWithLinearGradientColors(colorsArr: [CGColor]) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, false, self.scale);
    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
        return UIImage()
    }
    context.translateBy(x: 0, y: self.size.height)
    context.scaleBy(x: 1, y: -1)

    context.setBlendMode(.normal)
    let rect = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)

    // Create gradient
    let colors = colorsArr as CFArray
    let space = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let gradient = CGGradient(colorsSpace: space, colors: colors, locations: nil)

    // Apply gradient
    context.clip(to: rect, mask: self.cgImage!)
    context.drawLinearGradient(gradient!, start: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), end: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.size.height), options: .drawsAfterEndLocation)
    let gradientImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return gradientImage!
}
}
```

Answer (score 12):

I *believe* that the following should work - do comment if it doesn't!

```
// Load image
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MyCoolImage.png"];
CGFloat scale = image.scale;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(image.size.width * scale, image.size.height * scale));
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, image.size.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeMultiply);
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width * scale, image.size.height * scale);
CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, image.CGImage);

// Create gradient

UIColor *colorOne = ....;
UIColor *colorTwo = ....;

NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)colorOne.CGColor, (id)colorTwo.CGColor, nil];
CGColorSpaceRef space = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(space, (CFArrayRef)colors, NULL);

// Apply gradient

CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, image.CGImage);
CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, CGPointMake(0,0), CGPointMake(0,image.size.height * scale), 0);
CGGradientRelease(gradient);
UIImage *gradientImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Credit to [CoffeeShopped](http://coffeeshopped.com/2010/09/iphone-how-to-dynamically-color-a-uiimage) for the basic idea.

Comment: There were some errors but I managed to fix them. Thanks very much!

Comment: For my own knowledge, what were they, please?

Comment: 1. `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGPointMake(image.size.x * scale, image.size.y * scale));` (there should be .width and .height, not .x, .y + it should be CGRectMake, not CGPointMake) 2. `NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:colorOne.CGColor, colorTwo.CGColor, nil];` (there should be (id) before colorOne and colorTwo)

Comment: 1. Ah yes... 2. Really? Well, if it works for you, I can't argue :P

Comment: The answer by remy worked without fixes for both retina and non-retina displays.

Comment: There should be a CGGradientRelease(gradient) somewhere near the end, no?

Answer (score 5):

Swift version (as UIImage extension, using remy's answer ):

```
extension UIImage {
    func tintedWithLinearGradientColors(colorsArr: [CGColor!]) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, false, self.scale);
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, self.size.height)
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0)

        CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeNormal)
        let rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height)

        // Create gradient

        let colors = colorsArr as CFArray
        let space = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        let gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(space, colors, nil)

        // Apply gradient

        CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, self.CGImage)
        CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, CGPointMake(0, 0), CGPointMake(0, self.size.height), 0)
        let gradientImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return gradientImage
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
  
    
    //Original image displayed as is
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 200, height: 200)
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    view.addSubview(imageView)
    
    let myImageName = "image.png"
    let myImage = UIImage(named: myImageName)
    imageView.image = myImage
    
    //Let's change the image to Gradient Color
    let imageView2 = UIImageView()
    imageView2.frame = CGRect(x: 300, y: 50, width: 200, height: 200)
    imageView2.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    view.addSubview(imageView2)
    
    let myImageName2 = "apple_logo.png"
    let myImage2 = UIImage(named: myImageName2)
    imageView2.image = myImage2!.maskWithGradientColor(color: UIColor.red)
            
}
```

}

extension UIImage {
func maskWithGradientColor(color: UIColor) -> UIImage? {

```
    let maskImage = self.cgImage
    let width = self.size.width
    let height = self.size.height
    let bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)
    
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue)
    let bitmapContext = CGContext(data: nil,
                                  width: Int(width),
                                  height: Int(height),
                                  bitsPerComponent: 8,
                                  bytesPerRow: 0,
                                  space: colorSpace,
                                  bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo.rawValue)
    
    let locations:[CGFloat] = [0.0, 1.0]
    let bottom = UIColor(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1).cgColor
    let top = UIColor(red: 0, green: 1, blue: 0, alpha: 0).cgColor
    let colors = [top, bottom] as CFArray
    let gradient = CGGradient(colorsSpace: colorSpace, colors: colors, locations: locations)
    let startPoint = CGPoint(x: width/2, y: 0)
    let endPoint = CGPoint(x: width/2, y: height)
    
    bitmapContext!.clip(to: bounds, mask: maskImage!)
    bitmapContext!.drawLinearGradient(gradient!, start: startPoint, end: endPoint, options: CGGradientDrawingOptions(rawValue: UInt32(0)))
    
    if let cImage = bitmapContext!.makeImage() {
        let coloredImage = UIImage(cgImage: cImage)
        return coloredImage
    }
    else  {
        return nil
    }
}
```

}