# Gradient over UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, swift3, gradient

I've been trying to fill an image view with a gradient layer, but I can't seem to make it work, I tried to create CAGradientLayer, applied 2 colors on it then applied it as a mask to the main image layer.

```
let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
gradient.frame = (self.imageView?.bounds)!
gradient.colors = [UIColor.blue.cgColor, UIColor.purple.cgColor]
gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1.0)
gradient.locations = [0, 1]
self.imageView?.layer.mask = gradient
```

This is what I have, and this is what I want as a result:

[image: First] [image: Second]

UPDATE:
Found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098130/how-can-i-tint-a-uiimage-with-gradient).

Comment: You have it backwards.  You use the image to mask the gradient.  The thing with the alpha channel is always the mask because it provides the transparency info.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var gradient = CAGradientLayer()
gradient.frame = imageView.bounds
gradient.colors = [UIColor.blue.cgColor, UIColor.purple.cgColor]
imageView.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I did try this before, it draws a gradient over the image indeed, but it draws a gradient square over the image, it does not match the shape of the original image

Answer (score 0):

I got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47079456/11537677) answer. Add extension of UIImage and just pass colours list to apply gradient.

```
import UIKit

extension UIImage {

func tintedWithLinearGradientColors(colorsArr: [CGColor]) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, false, self.scale);
    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
        return UIImage()
    }
    context.translateBy(x: 0, y: self.size.height)
    context.scaleBy(x: 1, y: -1)

    context.setBlendMode(.normal)
    let rect = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)

    // Create gradient
    let colors = colorsArr as CFArray
    let space = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let gradient = CGGradient(colorsSpace: space, colors: colors, locations: nil)

    // Apply gradient
    context.clip(to: rect, mask: self.cgImage!)
    context.drawLinearGradient(gradient!, start: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), end: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.size.height), options: .drawsAfterEndLocation)
    let gradientImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return gradientImage!
}
}
```